# Htaccess redirect with many rules

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I got rewrite rules:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|static)\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301] //add www before adress

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s([^.]+)\.php [NC] //remove .php
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d //remove .php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php 

RewriteRule ^portfolio/([0-9]+)([^.]*)$ /portfolio-single.php?id=$1 [L]
```

But the last one dosent work, i want to have adress like www.mysite.com/portfolio/3-some-name => /portfolio-single.php?id=3

I dont know how to get i work.

(Sorry for my bad english)

Answer (score 0):

Change order of rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www|static)\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s([^.]+)\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^portfolio/([0-9]+) /portfolio-single.php?id=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: Is portfolio a directory? Are you getting 404 for `www.mysite.com/portfolio/3-some-name`?

Comment: no, portfolio isnt directory, www.mysite.com/portfolio/3-some-name gives me same as www.mysite.com/portfolio

Comment: And what does `www.mysite.com/portfolio` show? (none of the rule cover this case)

Comment: works for /portfolio/5 but error 404 for links like mysite.com/otherfile

Comment: How is `/otherfile` related to `/portfolio` problem?

Comment: i had redirection from /allfiles.php -> /allfiles and now its not working (its removing .php but get 404 error)

Comment: "300 Multile Choices" for /allfiles

Comment: Multiple Choices
The document name you requested (/oferta) could not be found on this server. However, we found documents with names similar to the one you requested.

Available documents:

    /oferta.php (common basename) 

Please consider informing the owner of the referring page about the broken link.

Comment: That is because you're using some other Apache module like mod_spelling or something else. I can only solve stated problem in question which I did.

Comment: added RewriteBase / and used my base rules and now works

Comment: Glad to know, can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.